# Alternatives to Talend Big data tool

Tags: bigdata, talend

i want to know other products like Talend.I would like to know competing products
Is there any? please suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CloverDX](http://www.cloverdx.com) and [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/) are two good options to consider.

Comment: You could consider https://mammoth.io too. (I am part of the team)