# How to gather files from different sources into HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, elasticsearch, sharepoint, hdfs

Currently I am working with a team that works on "search engines", especially with HP Idol,

The main idea of my work is to find a new search engine which is open source so that I started to work with Elasticsearch, but I still have some problems that I could not find solutions;

I need to index the documents into Elasticsearch from the servers of,

- Sharepoint
- Documentum
- Alfresco

so from my searches on the web, I found out,

- Talend ( can not use because, the team does not want to pay )
- Apache Manifoldcf (open source but lots of problem with it)

Have seen those problems, I continue to find out new solutions.
Can you please tell me if I have some possibilities to put all files from sources into HDFS and then index them all on Elasticsearch with Apache Spark ? 
I will appreciate also all your new techniques that I have never thought.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980571/alternatives-to-talend-big-data-tool

Comment: I've been investing this myself, I want to about the same only from a few additional sources such as Confluence to basically make a knowledge base search engine, elastic search seemed to be the way to go for cheap. I started by trying it's elk stack but haven't figured it all out yet. You can connect this to Hadoop services, I didn't used Hadoop hear since I don't have large data to index. If you are using Hadoop check out maybe apace solr , and Apace Tika. In the mean time I wrote some java script to search my engines until I figure out the whole stack.

Comment: Check out bitnami.org they have some demo virtual machines to try most of this stuff out.